# Python: efficient way to read text file with varying delimiters (spaces)

Tags: python

I am new to Python and I'm trying to figure out an efficient way to read a text file that is something like this:

```
   345   45678   567        678  78
   789   98733   456        567  67
```

the problem is that the columns are separated by spaces, but the number of spaces is not constant.

I came up with this:

```
def fileread(filename):
data=[]
with open(filename) as myfile:
    LINES=myfile.read().splitlines()
myfile.close()
for line in LINES:
    whole_line=line.split(' ')
    dataline=[]
    for element in whole_line:
        if(element!=''):
                dataline.append(int(element))
    data.append(dataline)
return data
```

but I feel like there must be a more efficient solution, which would be helpful since I'm gonna need this to read a bunch of very large files.

Can someone help me find one?

Thanks!

Comment: Use `numpy loadtxt` (http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html).

Comment: Try just `line.split()` instead of `line.split(' ')`

Comment: You don't need `myfile.close()` ... it's already handled by `with open...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this with a few lines of code, without any extra imports. Generators are great for this type of work.  That being said, pandas is worth looking into if you're working with large data sets often, it might change your life.

```
with open('text.txt') as f:
        data = f.read()

split = [x for x in data.split()]
```

Comment: I didn't realize that "split()" with no argument would do exactly what I needed. Thanks! And to http://stackoverflow.com/users/1531637/plasma, too.
I'll check out Pandas, too!

Answer (score 1):

I would try pandas.read_csv, with is a very capable csv reader.
http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html
It has the option to use regex as seperator, which would fit your use case very well.

Answer (score -1):

Use re library with regex, its an easy way to parse text.

```
import re
m = re.search('(?<=abc)def', 'abcdef')
m.group(0)

'def'
```